# Verb+Noun Parsers and Old School Visual Novels

Tags: lua

[image]

Hi 
I'm working on a simple old school visual novel engine in Lua. Basically I have most of the code set up besides one important feature. The Text Parser.

Lets get into how words are generally structured.
In the screenshot I input the command "my wish is for you to die"

--How would a human understand this?

my = noun/object

wish = verb

is = connective_equator similar to =

for = connective_object (for all objects of ..)

you = noun/object

to = connective_action similar to do

die = verb

--the computer can then parse this and understand it like this (pseudo example)

my = user

you = get_current_label()

you = "Lost Coatl"

wish = user_command

user_command = for all_objects of "Lost Coatl" do die() end

### execute user_command()

What other ways do videogames use text parsers, what would be the simplest way for a newbie coder such as myself?